# raphaeljs unable to handle rotated-rectangles from svg

Tags: svg, raphael, coreldraw

I am exporting a corel vector file to svg, and in turn importing into html/js via raphael-JS-svg library.

Apparently any 'rectangles' from the corel file that are rotated are causing various problems when rendered via raphael-JS.

One problem  is the strange thick borders around the rectangles (see right-side screenshot from web browser). Another problem (not shown) is that the rotated rectangles are not surviving raphael transforms (such as: `my_raphael_set.transform( "s.2,.2,0,0" )`).

Other than the solution to go into corel and change every rotated rectangle, any suggestions on:

- WHY ... is this happening?
- HOW ... to fix it?

[image]

COMPARISON between two rectangles as seen via firebug:

```
// BAD rectangle .... rotated by corel-author .... 
//                    generates 'transform' property into svg-element
 <rect x="0" y="0" 
       width="4.8969" 
       height="0.937656" 
       r="0" rx="0" ry="0" 
       fill="#00cccc" 
       stroke="#000000" 
       transform="matrix(8.2365,0.3452,0.3452,-8.2365,218.414,436.808)" 
       style="fill-opacity: 0.5;" 
       stroke-width="0.5" 
       data-svg="rect" 
       data-svg-group="Layer_x0020_1" 
       fill-opacity="0.5">



// GOOD rectangle .... not-rotated by corel-author .... 
//                     no 'transform' property into svg-element     
 <rect x="140.07" y="418.729" 
       width="40.3688" 
       height="7.72979" 
       r="0" rx="0" ry="0" 
       fill="#00cccc" 
       stroke="#000000" 
       style="fill-opacity: 0.5;" 
       stroke-width="0.5" 
       data-svg="rect" 
       data-svg-group="Layer_x0020_1" 
       fill-opacity="0.5">
```

Comment: I think realistically you will need to put some example isolated code and svg on a jsfiddle or something.

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution: in corel, use **arrange > convert to curves** for the rotated rectangles.

ideally I would like for raphael to somehow 'handle' the rotated rectangles, but the corel-fix is a fix, after all.